# Concatenate list of lists in one string - Python 3

Tags: python

I have a list of lists with int and string like this:

`l = [[1, "two", 3],["four", 5, "six"]]`.

I need to generate one string, startig a new line for each list, separeted by a semicolon. Like this:

```
"1, two, 3;
 four, 5, six;"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use ```print(";\n".join(", ".join(str(e) for e in sublist) for sublist in l) + ";")```

Comment: `';\n'.join([','.join(map(str, x)) for x in l])`

Answer (score 3):

```
print ";\n".join([", ".join([str(i) for i in s]) for s in l])
```

Comment: You need to add a final ";" to format as per the question :)